# Why useEffect don't react to dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i meet hard to understanding trouble with my react app. Getting an array from API and render his as table. Before rendering, the array must go into two functions - sort and pagination. Actually table working well but have behavior strange. Sort function does not react on dependencies and on first render i get empty array, after getting array from API this function must call new render but it doesn't happen.
*P\S: Pagination working on first render, trouble only with sort func*

**App.js**

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const {setMask, setCurrentColumn, setCurrentCondition, sortedItems} = useSort(items);
    const {setCurrentPage, currentItems, amountOfPages} = usePagination(sortedItems);
```

**Sort func**

```
const [sortedItems, setSortedItems] = useState([]);
    const [mask, setMask] = useState("");
    const [currentColumn, setCurrentColumn] = useState("");
    const [currentCondition, setCurrentCondition] = useState("");
    console.log(items);
    useEffect(() => {
        SortQuantity(currentCondition, currentColumn);
        SortDistance(currentCondition, currentColumn);
        SortName(currentCondition, currentColumn);

    }, [currentCondition, currentColumn, mask, items]);

    function SortQuantity(currentCondition, currentColumn) {
        if (currentColumn === "Quantity" && currentCondition === "less") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item => item.Quantity < mask)
            )
        } else if (currentColumn === "Quantity" && currentCondition === "greater") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item => item.Quantity > mask)
            )
        } else if (currentColumn === "Quantity" && currentCondition === "equal") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item => item.Quantity.toString() === mask)
            )
        } else return items
    }

    function SortDistance(currentCondition, currentColumn) {
        if (currentColumn === "Distance" && currentCondition === "less") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item => item.Distance < mask)
            )
        } else if (currentColumn === "Distance" && currentCondition === "greater") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item => item.Distance > mask)
            )
        } else if (currentColumn === "Distance" && currentCondition === "equal") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item => item.Distance.toString() === mask)
            )
        } else return items
    }

    function SortName(currentCondition, currentColumn) {
        if (currentColumn === "Name" && currentCondition === "contains") {
            console.log(mask, currentCondition, currentColumn);
            setSortedItems(
                items.filter(item =>
                    item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(mask.toLowerCase())
                )
            )
        } else return items
    }

    return {
        setMask,
        setCurrentColumn,
        setCurrentCondition,
        sortedItems
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the first render, but this is not the answer to the question. I added setSortedItems to fetch.

**App.js**

```
async function FetchData() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/items');
                const json = await response.json();
                setItems(json);
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setSortedItems(json);
                console.log(json);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        };
```